# How can I remove duplicate values from a list in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and stuck to a problem. I am using list for storing string values.
now i want to remove the duplicate values from that string. Can anyone tell me how do this.

Any sample code will be highly appreciate.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/

Comment: You want to remove duplicates from the String or the List? And have you tried anything ?

Comment: Answers to this question are a nice example of a list with duplicate values :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-c-vector

Comment: If possible, change your code to prevent inserting duplicate values when the list is generated. You might consider switching to another container, like `std::set` for this purpose.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/) followed by [`unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/unique/).

Comment: LOL!  I need to read the reference more myself apparently.  I didn't even know that was there.

Comment: @Noah: to be honest, I realized the existence of these member functions by googling the global `std::unique` from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @Noah: the question is, when do you really use a `list` ;) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: When you need to slice and splice, or need insertion/removal anywhere without invalidating any other iterators. :)

Comment: @Fred: this was rhetorical actually ;) I think the iterator invalidation is the strongest point anyway, but then I usually work with small (~5 ~20) datasets so I can splice vectors as easily.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I figured it was, but people so often forget about list splicing without any invalidation that it's fun to point out sometimes.

Comment: @Fred: Actually, I think it's the only example of "move" semantics in C++03  :)

Answer (score 14):

If the list is sorted, use its unique method.

If the list isn't sorted (and you don't want to sort it):

```
set<string> found;
for (list<string>::iterator x = the_list.begin(); x != the_list.end();) {
  if (!found.insert(*x).second) {
    x = the_list.erase(x);
  }
  else {
    ++x;
  }
}
```

To avoid copying the strings into the set:

```
struct less {
  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T &a, T &b) {
    return std::less<T>()(a, b);
  }
};
struct deref_less {
  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T a, T b) {
    return less()(*a, *b);
  }
};

void remove_unsorted_dupes(list<string> &the_list) {
  set<list<string>::iterator, deref_less> found;
  for (list<string>::iterator x = the_list.begin(); x != the_list.end();) {
    if (!found.insert(x).second) {
      x = the_list.erase(x);
    }
    else {
      ++x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for an example that doesn't destroy the existing order

Comment: Is there a common name for this `deref_less` comparator? I've been using one myself and had to think how to name it :S

Comment: @7vies: Deref_less makes sense to me: deref then (std::)less.  You could (and probably should) write it to actually use std::less: `return std::less<decltype(*a)>(*a, *b);`.

Comment: Interesting use of decltype, gotta remember that one!

Comment: @Xeo: It's the entire purpose of decltype. :) But it's 0x-only. In portable C++03, I'd write `struct my_less { template<class T> operator()(T &a, T &b) { return std::less<T>()(a, b); } }; struct deref_less { template<class T> bool operator()(T a, T b) { return my_less()(*a, *b); } };` to avoid compiler-specific pre-0x equivalents to decltype. (I also missed a set of parens in the comment.)

Answer (score 9):

If you have an `std::list` you can remove duplicates with:

```
yourlist.sort();
yourlist.unique();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use unique().

But *first* sort() the list, or unique won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
struct already_found
{
  std::set<std::string> & theSet;

  bool operator()(const std::string& s) const
  {
     return !theSet.insert(s).second;
  }
};

std::set<std::string> theSet;
the_list.remove_if( the_list.begin(), the_list.end(), already_found(theSet) );
```

Solution 2 using shared_ptr

```
struct already_found
{
  boost::shared_ptr<std::set<std::string> > theSet;
  already_found() : theSet( new boost::shared_ptr<std::set<std::string> > )
  {
  }

  bool operator()(const std::string& s) const
  {
     return !theSet->insert(s).second;
  }
};

the_list.remove_if( the_list.begin(), the_list.end(), already_found(theSet) );
```

These both have the disadvantage of having to copy all the strings. You can slightly optimise this by storing pointers to the strings and comparing them with a custom compare.

Comment: Already_found::op() is const, but it modifies theSet.

Comment: @Fred Nurk It's allowed to modify it. In one case it's a ref. In the other it's in a shared_ptr. The const does not propagate to it in either case.