# Remove duplicates from a list<int>

Tags: c++, stl

Using STL algorithms (as much as possible) such as `remove_if()` and `list::erase`, is there a nice way to remove duplicates from a list defined as following:

`list<int> l;`

Please note that `list::unique()` only works if duplication occurs in consecutive elements. In my case, all duplicates have to be eliminated regardless of their position in the list. Moreover, removing duplicates mean preserving only one copy of each element in the final result.

EDIT: The option to `l.sort()` followed by `l.unique()` cannot be availed as that will destroy the order of the list.

Comment: Well, obviously you could call `l.sort()` before calling `l.unique()`, but I assume there must be a reason why you can't do that? :)

Comment: Not sure about STL algorithms, but the obvious way to do this is to iterate through the list building a hash set: if each element isn't in the set it is unique so add to set; if it is in the set it's a duplicate so remove from list.

Comment: Why don't you propose us some code of yours ?

Comment: @hrnt I assume he wants to keep his current element order, notwithstanding duplicates

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877504/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-list-in-c/4877575#4877575

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `list::remove_if` member function, a temporary hashed set, and lambda expression.

```
std::list<int> l;
std::unordered_set<int> s;

l.remove_if([&](int n) {
    return (s.find(n) == s.end()) ? (s.insert(n), false) : true;
});
```

Comment: Note: This solution avoids the pitfall that I have noted on José Tomás Tocino's answer by having `s` be captured by reference .

Answer (score 8):

If preserving the order of the list is not important, you can just do `list.sort(); list.unique();`

If the order is important, use Rup's suggestion:

```
list<int>::iterator iter = l.begin();
set<int> elements;
while (iter != l.end()) {
  if (elements.find(*iter) != elements.end())
    iter = l.erase(iter);
  else {
    elements.insert(*iter);
    ++iter;
  }
}
```

Comment: otherwise: `if(elements.insert(*iter).second) ++iter else iter = l.erase(iter)`. set::insert returns a pair of which the second elements indicates whether insertion was successful, or failed because of a duplicate.

Comment: aren't you testing the wrong `end()` on the line containing `find()`?

Comment: @Hasturkun: yes I was. Fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks for the response...but aren't loops very STL-"unlike"?

Comment: @Jaywalker: Yeah, they are not very "STL-like". TheOm3ga's answer is more "STL-like" (with a few fixes).

Answer (score 6):

He said he wanted to use the erase-remove idiom, so here's a possible way, using a function object:

```
struct Unifier{
    set<int> foundElements;

    bool operator()(int & a){
        if(foundElements.find(a) != foundElements.end()){
            return true;
        }else{
            foundElements.insert(a);
            return false;
        }
    }
};


int main(){
    list<int> v;

    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(3);

    copy (v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));

    Unifier u;
    v.remove_if(u);

    cout << endl << "After:" << endl;
    copy (v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));

}
```

---

**Update**: The above code has a subtle bug. According to C++11 `[algorithms.general]/10`:

> [Note: Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely. Programmers for whom object identity is important should consider using a wrapper class that points to a noncopied implementation object such as `reference_wrapper<T>` (20.8.3), or some equivalent solution. —end note ]

There appears to be no "otherwise specified" for `std::list::remove_if`, so this code may fail to remove all duplicates because it may create copies of the predicate at the start, and then use different copies of the predicate for different parts of the list. [Example of this actually happening for std::remove_if](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a3ca9a84465c908).

A simple fix for C++11 is to replace `v.remove_if(u)` with:

```
v.remove_if( reference_wrapper<decltype(u)>(u) );
```

In C++03 I'm not sure if the above quote was present; but if it was then a fix would be to make `foundElements` be static, or to refactor `Unifier` so that all copies of it reference a single instance of `foundElements`.

[Link to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397616/what-is-wrong-with-stdset/)

Comment: Why do you take the a parameter by reference?

Comment: You do not need to use erase-remove idiom with std::list. You could just call v.remove_if(u); Also, your foundElements does not need to be static.

Comment: You actually don't want `foundElements` to be `static`.  If you used the functor again, it would already have the set of entries from the previous run in it, which wouldn't give you correct results on future runs.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought at first, but it was giving me weird problems, so I used static in a hurry. But I agree it's supposed not to be necessary.

Comment: Please make these changes so that I can accept this as the most accurrate answer :) `v.remove_if (u)` should be used and `foundElements` need not be `static.`