# Inbuilt hashtable in C++

Tags: c++, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I want to know whether C++ has any inbuilt library to implement hash tables. Basically I want to use it to remove duplicates from a linked list. And for this I want to use inbuilt C++ hash table. I would be really great if anyone help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C++ does *not* have any such thing (as opposed to some other languages), but its standard library does.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885676/remove-duplicates-from-a-listint) for an implementation using `remove_if` and `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 4):

Following hash table data structures are available with standard template library:

```
std::unordered_set 
std::unordered_multiset 
std::unordered_map
```

and `std::unordered_mutimap` are using hash table

In your specific case, I think `std::unordered_set` may be enough.