# How to remove duplicates from std::vector <std::pair<UnicodeString, UnicodeString> >

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

how to remove duplicate values from

```
std::vector <std::pair<UnicodeString, UnicodeString> > myVect;
```

Is there any built in function or i need to write a custom code for this

Comment: unique() removes adjacent duplicates, so you can sort your vector and then do a unique().

Comment: If you wish to only have unique values in your container, consider using std::set.

Comment: Take a look at similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-c-vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that (a) a `std::set` is not what you want [that is you want to allow duplicate elements in your `std::vector`, only to remove them later] and (b) you don't wish to change the order of the elements in your `std::vector` [that is, the current order is important], which are both reasonable situations...  You should be able to adapt [Fred Nurk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877504/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-list-in-c/4877575#4877575) to [How can I remove duplicate values from a list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4877504/78845) buy substituting `vector` for `list` and modifying the `less` comparators accordingly.

Comment: But, if he uses Fred's answer with `vector`, won't he get O(N^2) behavior, since `vector::erase()` is O(N) while `list::erase()` is O(1)? Is there a solution that works well with vectors?

Comment: @Rob: Good point. Since, I don't know (a) whether `std::set` is acceptable, (b) whether @jame can `sort` the vector or (c) whether speed is an issue, I'll leave my answer as-is for now.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it, if you can modify the order in your vector is the following:

```
   std::sort(myVect.begin(), myVect.end());
   myVect.erase(std::unique(myVect.begin(), myVect.end()), myVect.end());
```

Just make sure UnicodeString accepts the < operator.

However, you may want to use a different structure such as std::set or std::unordered_set to have an unique guarantee at insertion.