# erasing duplicate element on even index in STL vector

Tags: c++, stl

I know how to erase duplicate element(s) on a vector.

```
data.erase(std::unique(data.begin(), data.end()), data.end());
```

How do I erase duplicate elements on index 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...?

Example:

```
 index : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 data  : a b a d b f a h b k
         ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
         ^   ^   ^   ^
                 ^--same-^
         ^   ^       ^
         ^   ^       ^ 
         ^-----same--^  
after erasing
data  :  a b   d b f   h   k

after concatenatiom
data :   a b d b f h
```

Comment: Do you want to erase all duplicates (as your example seems to suggest), or just the **adjacent** ones (which is what `std::unique` does)?

Comment: either your example is wrong, or your approach using `erase` and `std::unique` doesn't solve this problem. Please clarify this.

Comment: BTW, why is "k" not in the end result in your example?

Answer (score 2):

There's no library function for this.  What you're asking to do isn't even analogous to using `std::unique` as you did in your example, since that only removes *adjacent* duplicates.  You'll have to do most of the work here yourself.

Create a set.  Loop through the vector, skipping the odd indexes.  As you loop, check if that element is in the set.  If it is, mark that index for removal, otherwise, add the element to the set.  Remove all marked indexes from the vector.  You can't use `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`, since those work on element values, not indexes.  You'll have to use a plain old for loop.

Although, if you designate a certain value as illegal, then instead of keeping track of indexes, you can actually change the element to that illegal value.  Then you *can* use `std::remove`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a particularly elegant code, but it should work as long as default hashing and comparison is sufficient, and should be reasonably efficient:

```
template <typename T>
void RemoveEvenDuplicates(std::vector<T>& v) {

    std::unordered_set<T> s;
    std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0;

    auto last = std::remove_if(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        [&s, &i] (const T& element) -> bool {
            if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
                auto pair = s.insert(element);
                return !pair.second;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    v.erase(last, v.end());

}

void main() {

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("d");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("f");
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("h");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("k");

    RemoveEvenDuplicates(v);

}
```

After the call to `RemoveEvenDuplicates`, the vector becomes:

```
[7]("a","b","d","b","f","h","k")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take (one of) the suggestion(s) given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877504/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-list-in-c/4877575#4877575) very good post by [Fred Nurk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511601/fred-nurk) to a very similar question.
You will need an additional `++x;` to touch only the even (or odd) indexed elements.

Example:

```
set<string> found;
for (list<string>::iterator x = the_list.begin(); x != the_list.end();) {
  if (!found.insert(*x).second) {
    x = the_list.erase(x);
  }
  else {
    ++x;
  }
  ++x; // <-- one increment added to skip the odd-indexed elements
}
```