# C++ finding doubles in list

Tags: c++, list, compare

I have to find if there are doubles in my `list<SnakeParts>` and set alive to false if there are doubles

I tried with the `unique()` function of the `list` and added an `operator==()` to my class.
now when I execute the unique function I doesn't filter out the doubles. and after some debugging I found out that the `==` comparator only get's exececuted as many times as there are objects in my list I used the following code:

```
list<SnakePart> uniquelist = m_snakeParts;
uniquelist.unique();
if (m_snakeParts.size() != uniquelist.size()){
    alive = false;
}
```

operator:

```
bool SnakePart::operator==(const SnakePart& snakePart) const{
    return (x == snakePart.x && y == snakePart.y );
}
```

but that doesn't work. so what am I doing wrong, or is there another way I could do this?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877504/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-list-in-c  ...Also, is this a snake game? if so you should only check that the Head (first of the list) isn't duplicated in the list

Answer (score 2):

`std::list::unique` works only with consecutive duplicates. Say, if we have a `{1, 2, 2, 1}`, after calling `unique` we got `{1, 2, 1}`. You could use `sort` function before(`N * log(N) + N` complexity) , or use `std::map` to count every element in list(linear, + N memory(in worst case)).

Answer (score 1):

> Notice that an element is only removed from the list container if it compares equal to the element immediately preceding it. Thus, this function is especially useful for sorted lists.

So you'll have to either sort your list beforehand, or use an std::set (sets by nature can't contain duplicate objects).

Answer (score 1):

If using a `std::list` is not a requirement then I would suggest using [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) which won't allow you to [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) an element that's already in the set. Moreover, the `insert` method will let you know if the element you are trying to insert is already in the set or not via its return value.

If using a `std::list` is a requirement, then I would suggest you to use [`std::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) algorithm to weed out the duplicates. Please have a look at the example in there.