# Which the better way to sort distinct numbers?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

In C++ using STL which of the two operations take less CPU time to sort large distinct numbers:

- Push the elements into a set
- Store the elements in a vector and call sort() function?

Comment: I tried for smaller inputs

Comment: why do people try to micro-optimize?

Comment: Why would you want to use the STL? Come pop along to the 21st century with us!

Comment: @Arun Now try for larger inputs, and you'll have your answer, won't you?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Is there a better way than using STL?

Comment: Are you worried about insertion time or just sorting time?  Sounds like it's time for your to prototype a bit.

Comment: @Arun: he's referring to the fact that, technically, STL was a library from SGI that slightly adapted to become the current containers/algorithms part of the C++ standard library; so, what you are referring to is not technically the STL, although it is still colloquially called so. It's quite a usual (and useless, if you ask me) exercise in nitpicking in the C++ tag.

Comment: @Arun It's about the use of the _word_ STL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about

Comment: Related (but not the same, as removing duplicates is involved): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1041939/777186

Comment: Just throw them into a std::set<>, then iterate. Done.

Comment: @Arun You should use Standard Library algorithms and containers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: so, I suppose that, when you are in a hurry, you have lunch at «the place that sells baked goods filled with dairy and meat-derived products and vegetables, as well as beverages most of which are carbonated» :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia That is a most accurate assessment, indeed! (What I _don't_ do is pop along to the local tavern for some hop-skotch and mead.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a one-off operation, I would use a `std::vector` followed by a `std::sort`.

As far as asymptotic complexity is involved, the two solutions should be equivalent: insertion in a set is O(log(n)), and you do that for N elements, so it's O(N log(N)) ([proof](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20N-%3E%2binf%20%28sum%20for%20i%20=%201%20to%20N%20log%28i%29%29%20/%20%28N%20%2a%20log%28N%29%29)).

On the other hand, insertion in a vector (provided that you know the size in advance) is O(N), and sorting is O(N log(N)), so globally it's O(N log(N)).

*But*: a vector requires a one-off allocation (or, if you don't know the final size, it should reach the definitive size in O(log(N)) reallocations on typical implementations); on the other hand, a set, if implemented as an RB tree, requires an allocation for each node, which means that you have to call the allocator N times - and allocator calls, in a POD container, are probably going to be one of the bottlenecks. Also, a tree typically has less cache locality *and* uses more memory, so all this overhead is probably going to hurt performance.

Also, big-O notation shows the functional time dependency, but hides the multiplicative constants; don't take my word for this, but I'm almost sure that N*set insertion is going to cost more than a single sort at the end due to all the extra bookkeeping to do for each element (a tree insertion often needs some work to restore the RB tree properties).

---

On the other hand, if you have to *keep* your data structure sorted (with new data coming by the by) the set is usually the correct solution.

---

But, as always, when in doubt *profile*.