# Deleting string elements in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have to input a integer number, and then a a string with n elements, int type;
The task is to delete the repeating elements. I tried to resolve the problem with this code, but don't know where is the mistake. Can you help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, br=0;

    string masiv;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>masiv[i];
    }
    n=masiv.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(masiv[i]==masiv[j] && i!=j)
            {
                masiv.erase (std::remove(masiv.begin(), masiv.end(), masiv[i]), masiv.end());
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<masiv<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most general (for example, works with const string too) way is to do the opposite of removing parts: copy the parts you do want into a new string in correct order, instead of repeatedly modifying the source string. This also applies if you use vector or whatever, instead of a string.

Comment: You are using a string to store integer values. Is that logical? You can refer to this link for your task [Most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a c++ vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-c-vector)

Comment: Your program has lots of issues.  A `std::string` always stores `char`, though you can instantiate `basic_string<int>` or use a `vector<int>` to store `int`s.  Given `char` is normally an `8` bit `int`, you can store numbers into it but it may not work as expected outside the range 0..127.  You need to add to the string using `+=`, not index ala `[i]` to locations that don't yet exist.

Comment: The other big issues in getting your code working: 1) you remove elements inside your loops, but always use j++ or i++ to jump over the index just considered - if you'd done a deletion a new element would have slotted in there and you'd skip it; 2) the size() changes when you delete elements, so you keep processing the erased elements - in this case the `vector` `capacity()` will be enough for these off-the-end accesses, but an implementation may still check for this and abort/throw etc..

Comment: Why not use set<string> to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int n, br=0;

        string masiv="";
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            char c;
            cin>>c;
            masiv += c;
        }
        n=masiv.size();
        string result="";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            bool repeated = false;
            for(int j=0;j<result.size();j++)
            {
                if(masiv[i]==result[j])
                {
                    repeated = true; // indicating that massiv[i] was added before
                }
            }
            if(repeated == false)
            {
                result += masiv[i]; // won't add masiv[i] to the result unless it's the first time encountered 
            }
        }
        cout<<result<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The existing code implies that repeating elements should be output once, rather than discarded altogether, but maybe it's wrong there given the question wording is consistent with what you've done...?

Comment: But that way keeps one of the repeating elements. I need to erase all elements, that are repeating minimum twice

Comment: This answer doesn't delete elements in a string, just ignores the repeated ones and creates a new string of the non-repeated elements. Which is also irrelevant to the OP's question. Not to mention it does not do any explanation about the code fixes, therefore -1.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the input into a character and use `push_back()` to save the read character into the string.

```
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    char c;
    cin>>c;
    masiv.push_back(c);
}
```

You are getting segmentation fault because you save the size of the string into value n (`n=masiv.size();`) which you shouldn't because once you erase an element from the string, its size changes. Therefore you should use `size()` method for the loop boundary as below.

```
for(int i=0;i<masiv.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<masiv.size();j++)
    {
        if(masiv[i]==masiv[j] && i!=j)
        {
            masiv.erase(j, 1);
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

See how smiple `erase()` method is? Just erase the repeated element (latter one). `j` specifices the indice of the repeated element and `1` specifies the character count that will be deleted starting from that indice. You have to decrement `j` because once you erase the character at the jth indice, now j will be pointing to the next character. When inner loop continues it will increment `j`. If you do not adjust the indice after erasing a character, you will skip a character when the loop increments. You have to adjust `j` to point to the correct index. Therefore `j--;`.

**Edit: Better loops**

You can re-arrange your loops in a way that you do not have to check whether `i==j` or not. Just start the inner loops index just 1 larger than that of outer loops.

```
for(int i=0;i<masiv.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<masiv.size();j++)
    {
        if(masiv[i]==masiv[j])
        {
            masiv.erase(j--, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume you have entered `level` as the string. The outer loop starts from `l` and inner loop starts from `e`. By this way you make less iterations and guarantee not to compare same indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // std::unique, std::distance
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::string masiv;
    int n; 
    std::cin >> n;
    assert( n > 0);
    std::cin.ignore(10,'\n');   // ignore 

    std::getline(std::cin,masiv);
    masiv.resize(n);

    std::string::iterator it = std::unique (masiv.begin(), masiv.end());
    masiv.resize( std::distance(masiv.begin(),it) );

    std::cout << masiv << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```