# Handling duplicated array elements

Tags: arrays, duplicate-data

I am in trouble handling duplicated elements in arrays. For example, in the problem of finding all pairs of integers within an array which sum to a specified value, here is my implementation:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> find_all_pairs_with_sum(int data[], int length, int sum)
{
    assert(data && length>1);

    vector<pair<int, int>> res;

    sort(data, data+length);

    int first = 0; 
    int last = length - 1; 
    while (first < last) 
    { 
        int s = data[first] + data[last]; 
        if (s == sum) 
        {
            res.push_back(make_pair(data[first], data[last]));

            ++first; 
            --last; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            if (s < sum)
                ++first; 
            else
                --last; 
        } 
    } 

    return res;
}
```

The problem will occur when the array contains duplicated elements. For example, when

```
int data[] = {3, 4, 3, 4};
int sum = 7;
```

The program will only give two pairs `(3,4) (3,4)`. However, in this case, the correct answer should be four pairs `(3,4) (3,4) (3,4) (3,4)` (as 4=2x2). How can I modify the code  in order to correctly handle such cases (hopefully still in `O(n logn)`)? It seems the change should be made in `if (s==sum)` scope while updating `first` and `last`, but I just cannot make it right.

*Note that: I know another way that can handle this correctly by using a `hash table` to record occurrences of each elements. Please suggest how to work through this problem without using a `hash table`.*

Comment: An interesting post: [STL - most efficient way to erae duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-c-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array gets sorted as

```
  Index: 0 1 2 3
Element: 3 3 4 4
```

When you find a sum, you increment `first` and decrement `last`, so each pair is only added once, not twice. Additionally, steping inward at any rate will always prevent you from getting both 1-3 and 0-2 (by index). You could make a preliminary pass to find duplicates, and use that information to add the pairs correctly:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> find_all_pairs_with_sum(int data[], int length, int sum)
{
    assert(data && length>1);

    vector<pair<int, int>> res;
    int i;

    sort(data, data+length);

    // there is more than one way to skin this cat...
    vector<pair<int, int>> vettedData;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(i == 0 || vettedData[vettedData.size() - 1].first != data[i])
            vettedData.push_back(make_pair(data[i], 1));
        else
            vettedData[vettedData.size() - 1].second++;
    }

    int first = 0; 
    int last = vettedData.size() - 1; 
    while (first < last) 
    { 
        int s = vettedData[first].first + vettedData[last].first; 
        if (s == sum) 
        {
            int iterations = vettedData[first].second * vettedData[last].second;
            for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                res.push_back(make_pair(vettedData[first].first, vettedData[last].first));

            ++first; 
            --last; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            if (s < sum)
                ++first; 
            else
                --last; 
        } 
    } 

    return res;
}
```

Comment: No, it still gives the same two pairs.

Comment: Good point. I actually got 3 pairs when I ran it, not 2 though. You have to search the entire array.

Comment: This becomes `O(N^2)`. Not really what I am looking for.

Comment: Then you'll have to make a preliminary pass to find repeats.

Comment: Thanks for your update. However, it will fail for case `{3, 4, 3}` and `sum=7`. Please have a check.

Comment: I know how to fix it. Updated your code. It worked now, thanks again.