# Arranging elements from two vectors alphabetically into one vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, alphabetical

The two vectors the user enters will always be in alphabetical order, and the function `merge_items` places those values in one vector seeing which one comes before the other by using the < operator, the code initially gave a segmentation fault and at certain times, it doesn't show the last element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void merge_items(vector<string>& a1,vector<string>& b1,vector<string>& merged);

int main(){
vector<string> v1,v2;
string a,b;
int n1,n2;
cout << "How many values for v1? " << endl;
cin >> n1;
for(int i = 0;i < n1;i++){
    cin >> a;
    v1.push_back(a);
}
cout << "How many values for v2? " << endl;
cin >> n2;
for(int i = 0;i < n2;i++){
    cin >> b;
    v2.push_back(b);
}

vector<string> merge;

merge_items(v1, v2, merge);

for(int i = 0;i < merge.size();i++){
    cout << merge[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}

void merge_items(vector<string>& a1,vector<string>& b1,vector<string>& merged){         int i1 = 0,i2 = 0;
string temp;
while(i1+i2 < (a1.size()-1+b1.size()-1)){
    if(a1[i1] < b1[i2]){
        temp = a1[i1];
        merged.push_back(temp);
        i1++;

    }else{
        temp = b1[i2];
        merged.push_back(temp);
        i2++;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can push back `a1[i1]` directly, there's no need to copy it into a local variable. I suppose this is an exercise, otherwise I would be tempted just to append both vectors to merged and then sort it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894919/merging-vectors)

Answer (score 2):

This is the appropriate way to merge:

```
std::merge(a1.begin(), a1.end(),
           b1.begin(), b1.end(),
           std::back_inserter(merged));
```

As far as what's wrong with your solution. A couple things.

First, once you reach the end of one of the two vectors, you need to stop comparing against that vector and just copy whatever elements are left from the other vector. So you need to compare `i1` against `a1.size()`, separately from your comparison of `i2` against `b1.size()`. With what you're doing now, when you reach the end of one vector, you continue comparing against out of bounds elements from that vector, which is undefined behavior, and likely the cause of your segmentation faults.

Second, you don't need to be subtracting 1 from the size of the vectors. The way you're doing it will leave you with a merged vector which has 2 fewer elements than the combined sizes of the source vectors.

Comment: Cool I didn't know about that merge function.

Comment: Can we use this function merge two source vector into one of source vector? If no, does STL has a function to do that?Thanks

Comment: @RonTang: No, you cannot, and no, it does not. There is [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) though, which allows you to merge two adjacent sorted ranges in place. In other words, if you have, for example, a vector with the first half sorted, and the second half sorted, you can merge them so the whole vector is sorted.