# Logic error using .erase (C++)

Tags: c++, logic

So my program is just reading an input of numbers and lists them in order. As seen in the output. 
***Without*** the use of the algorithm library, I sorted it and getting rid of repeated data. However, if there is a data value repeated, the last value of the vector is not printed. Am I incorrectly using the .erase?

```
void remove_repeated(int size, vector<int>& num_vec){
    for(int i = 0; i < num_vec.size(); i++){
        if(num_vec[i]==num_vec[i+1]){
            num_vec.erase((num_vec.begin()+i));
        }   
    }
}
```

Output when no value is repeated:

```
                 **Welcome to the HW Reading Program**
 Please, enter your HW:1-10

 Do Problems: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,and 10
```

Output when a value is repeated:

```
                 **Welcome to the HW Reading Program**
 Please, enter your HW: 1-10,1-3

 Do Problems: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,and 9
```

Comment: A) MVCE B) Fix your indentation. TIA.

Comment: That is a lot of irrelevant code you've posted.  You could have just posted  a simple `main` program, fill a vector with repeated hard-coded values, and simply call `remove_repeated` to see how it operates.  Sorting has nothing to do with the issue you're having.

Comment: @Borgleader A) I fixed it to the best of my ability.  B) What part of my indentation is not acceptable?

Comment: @Pouya -- [Please see this as to what a Minimal, Compilable, and Verifiable Example denotes](https://ideone.com/tW31Eg).  No need to show sorts, prompts, or anything else.  We see that the function is faulty from the given test data.

Comment: An example of a MCVE for this question: https://ideone.com/XV9P3G Note how it does nothing except run `remove_repeated` on a `vector` designed to expose the error and print out the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you erase element at index `i` from the vector, the next element is at index `i`, not at index `i+1`. Also you have to take care not to go out of bounds when comparing to `i+1`, ie your loop has to look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_vec.size()-1;){
    if(num_vec[i]==num_vec[i+1]){
        num_vec.erase((num_vec.begin()+i));
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also you should consider to use what the standard library has to offer. A `set` contains only unique elements, or you can use `erase`+`unique` (see eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041939/4117728) for more details).