# unique values in stl vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have following code which calculates unique values in vector

```
bool uniqueCompressVectorCompareFunction (unsigned int num1, unsigned int num2) {
  return (num1 == num2);
}


// redirect input from stream to file.
std::ifstream inputFile("testinput.txt");
std::streambuf* pcurrRdBuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
std::cin.set_rdbuf(inputFile.rdbuf());

unsigned int uiNoOfFishes = 0;
std::cin >> uiNoOfFishes;
std::vector<unsigned int> vecOfLenOfFishes(uiNoOfFishes);
std::vector<unsigned int> vecOfTimeHeadOfFishes(uiNoOfFishes);

// get length of fishes
for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx < uiNoOfFishes; uiIdx++) {
    std::cin >> vecOfLenOfFishes[uiIdx];
}

// get time head of fishes
for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx < uiNoOfFishes; uiIdx++) {
    std::cin >> vecOfTimeHeadOfFishes[uiIdx];
}

std::cout << "Actual input length of fishes: " << std::endl;
for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx <vecOfLenOfFishes.size(); uiIdx++) {
    std::cout << vecOfLenOfFishes[uiIdx] << "   ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Actual input time head of fishes: " << std::endl;
for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx <vecOfTimeHeadOfFishes.size(); uiIdx++) {
    std::cout << vecOfTimeHeadOfFishes[uiIdx] << "   ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;


std::vector<unsigned int> vecUniqueInputValues;
// copy length of fishes.
unsigned int uiUniqueVecIdx = 0;
for(; uiUniqueVecIdx < uiNoOfFishes; uiUniqueVecIdx++) {
    vecUniqueInputValues.push_back(vecOfLenOfFishes[uiUniqueVecIdx]);
}

// copy time head of fishes.
for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx < uiNoOfFishes; uiIdx++, uiUniqueVecIdx++) {
    vecUniqueInputValues.push_back( vecOfTimeHeadOfFishes[uiIdx]);
}

// using predicate comparison:
std::unique (vecUniqueInputValues.begin(), vecUniqueInputValues.end(), uniqueCompressVectorCompareFunction); 



std::cout << "compressInputData unique values sorted: " << std::endl;
for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx <vecUniqueInputValues.size(); uiIdx++) {
    std::cout << vecUniqueInputValues[uiIdx] << "   ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

// contents in testinput.txt is shonw below

```
5
2 4 4 2 4
1 4 1 6 4
```

Output is shown as below

```
Actual input length of fishes:
2   4   4   2   4
Actual input time head of fishes:
1   4   1   6   4
compressInputData total values:
2   4   4   2   4   1   4   1   6   4
compressInputData unique values sorted:
2   4   2   4   1   4   1   6   4   4
```

I am expecting compress input unique values should be
1 2 4 6

What is bug in my code?

Comment: You have to sort the vector before the std::unique:
See the example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique
Otherwise, you could use a std::unordered_set to keep unique values

Comment: It's probably due to your reduction of the actual code, but the function `uniqueCompressVectorCompareFunction` should never exist. Instead, just leave out the functor argument if you actually just do an equality comparison.

Comment: A similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) it

> [e]liminates all but the first element from every **consecutive** group of equivalent elements

(emphasis mine).

So it doesn't remove all recurring values, just the ones that are adjacent, reducing for example `[1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 2 2]` to `[1 2 3 1 3 2]`.

If you only want to keep the overall unique elements, you should sort the vector first:

```
std::sort(vecUniqueInputValues.begin(), vecUniqueInputValues.end());

// Vector is now [1, 1, 2, 2, .., 2, 4, .., 4, 5, ... ]

std::unique (vecUniqueInputValues.begin(), vecUniqueInputValues.end(), 
  uniqueCompressVectorCompareFunction);
```

### Some minor points

The comparison function seems a bit redundant -- if you don't specify it

> [e]lements are compared using `operator==`.

Also note that `std::unique` really only shuffles the elements around so that all the unique consecutive elements are at the start of the vector - you still see the value `4` twice at the end of your output. You should grab the result of `std::unique` - it is an iterator pointing one past the end of the unique range:

```
auto endOfUniqueRange = std::unique(...);

std::cout << "compressInputData unique values sorted: " << std::endl;
for(auto& uiIt = vecUniqueInputValues.cbegin(); uiIt != endOfUniqueRange ; ++uiIt) {
    std::cout << *uiIt << "   ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Actually I recommend that you use iterators and range-based for loops anyway: instead of

```
for(auto i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i) {
  // Do something with myVec[i]
}
```

write

```
for(auto it = myVec.cbegin(); it != myVec.cend(); ++it) {
  // Do something with *it
}
```

or, to iterate the whole vector,

```
for(unsigned int val : myVec) { 
  // Do something with val
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique):

> `std::unique` Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range `[first, last)` and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

see the word *consecutive*, this means that it would only remove the duplicates if the vector is sorted, and the repetitions are in consecutive order.

Sort the vector before calling `std::unique`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, `std::unique` removes consecutive duplicates. This allows it to be a single pass algorithm.

If you want to remove non-consecutive duplicates without changing the order of remaining elements, you'll have to write a different function to do it. This will generally require multiple passes over the input range.

Here is a simple implementation, to match the signature of `std::unique`

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator multipass_unique(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        // Search the whole range for values that are equal to the current
        // Any values removed shorten the range to search
        last = std::remove(std::next(first), last, *first);
    }
    return last;
}
```

And a variant that accepts a `BinaryPredicate`

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIterator multipass_unique(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, BinaryPredicate pred)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        // Search the whole range for values that satisfy the predicate
        // Any values removed shorten the range to search
        last = std::remove_if(std::next(first), last, [=](auto val){ return pred(*first, val); });
    }
    return last;
}
```

Comment: You can still do it in a single pass. For example, you could add all the elements you've seen to a hash set. While scanning the vector, you either encounter an element already in the set and you remove it, or you encounter an element that you haven't seen: leave it and add it to the set. Not O(1), but single pass.

Comment: @CompuChip that requires copyable values and additional allocation