# Remove duplicate elements from 2 separate arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, subtraction

How would i go about subtracting elements from 2 arrays?

I have my `array_1[5]` array with elements `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `array_2[3]` with elements `{2, 3, 5}`. In math class i was thought that i only need to subtract the groups to be left with `{1, 4}`. I have tried subtracting the arrays like integers but i can't figure out how to properly use the index. I have also tried sorting and the second array and then checking if their indexes are equal but that doesn't work.

How can i get this done in C++ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector)

Comment: You can't "remove" anything from an array. You need to use a vector.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the difference between two sets which is one of the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int array_1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int array_2[] = { 2, 3, 5 };

std::vector<int> difference;

std::set_difference(std::begin(array_1), std::end(array_1), std::begin(array_2), std::end(array_2), std::back_inserter(difference));

// difference now contains { 1, 4 }
```

Based on your comments, I suggest you have your arrays as std::vectors. Then it becomes simpler.

```
std::vector<int> array_1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> array_2 = { 2, 3, 5 };

std::set_difference(array_1.begin(), array_1.end(), array_2.begin(), array_2.end(), std::back_inserter(difference));
```

Comment: Yes you can. Are you compiling with C++11 support because my answer uses std::begin/end which were introduced then. What are the errors?

Comment: Compile with switch `-std=c++11`

Comment: Too little information means I can't troubleshoot this for you. See my edit for an alternative.