# Delete duplicates from array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

I am trying to create a simple program which calls on 2 functions.
The first function takes a partially filled array, loops through it and deletes any duplicate values. When a value is deleted from the array, the remaining numbers are moved backwards to fill the gap i.e. when the function is finished, all null values of the array will be together at the end.

The second function prints the updated array.

My current code is below. At present when I run my code, the console shows:
`2 6 0 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460`.
It should be showing:
`1 2 5 6`

Also, I am not sure how to move the remaining elements of the array backwards so that the null values will be together at the end.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void deleteRepeats(int *arr, int arraySize, int& posUsed);
void printArray(int *arr, int arraySize);

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 1};
    int posUsed = 6;
    int arraySize = 10;


    deleteRepeats(arr, arraySize, posUsed);
    printArray(arr, arraySize);

    return 0;
}

void deleteRepeats(int *arr, int arraySize, int& posUsed)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < arraySize; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < arraySize; k++)
                {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];

                }
                posUsed--;
            
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int *arr, int arraySize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr` only has room for 6 elements, but you set `arraySize = 10`. You can change to `int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 1 };`

Comment: Would there be a possibility to use `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp I have corrected this. Although I have the same problem with console showing no output. Micha, my lecturer does not want us to use vectors, as we have not covered them yet

Comment: Also, `arr[k] = arr[k + 1];` will read past the end of the array when `k = arraySize - 1`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyMopp. I have updated my code with your corrections.

Comment: In your `for` loops you need to use `posUsed` and not `arraySize`.

Comment: I changed the 3 to posUsed. My console output is now: 2 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. While it should be 1 2 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: You've modified the code since you originally posted the question. Most importantly, you modified the 2nd `for` loop. So now you end up incrementing `j` twice.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the relative order of elements in your array? For example: Input: {6, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1}, Output: the same as before, or {6, 1, 2, 5}?

Comment: Using algorithms -- `auto ptr = std::unique(arr, arr + arraySize); std::fill(ptr, arr + arraySize, 0);`  Any reason why this cannot be accepted as an answer?  Can you use the algorithm functions (which **can** work with regular arrays)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Your code obviously cannot be accepted while it's in a comment. BTW I haven't used `std::unique` recently, but from what I know about standard library, it only implements algorithms which are efficient. So it will only delete adjacent duplicates.

Comment: Yes @anatolyg `std::unique` will not work in this example unless you use `std::sort` beforehand. But again - this is a solution only if order of the elements doesn't matter (still waiting for OP to confirm/deny).

Comment: Yes, `std::sort` will also work with arrays.  So solution is 3 lines instead of 2 (if algorithms can be used) (sort, unique, fill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your assignment constraints (more C-like, than idiomatic C++), you can rewrite your function like this, to make it work:

```
void deleteRepeats(int *arr, int arraySize, int& posUsed)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < posUsed; ++i)
    {
        int duplicates = 0;
        int j = i + 1;
        // find the first duplicate, if exists
        for ( ; j < posUsed; ++j)
        {
            if ( arr[i] == arr[j] ) {
                ++duplicates;
                break;
            }
        }
        // overwrite the duplicated values moving the rest of the elements...
        for (int k = j + 1; k < posUsed; ++k)
        {
            if (arr[i] != arr[k])
            {
                arr[j] = arr[k];
                ++j;
            }
            // ...but skip other duplicates
            else
            {
                ++duplicates;    
            }
        }
        posUsed -= duplicates;
    }
    // clean up (could be limited to the duplicates only)
    for (int i = posUsed; i < arraySize; ++i)
        arr[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would let the std containers to what you like to do.

- Sort the vector
- Use `erase` and `unique` to delete duplicates.

Here is the code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void print(const std::vector<int> &arr){
    for (const auto & i : arr){
        std::cout << i <<" ";
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr{1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 1};    
    print(arr);

    std::sort( arr.begin(), arr.end() );
    arr.erase( std::unique( arr.begin(), arr.end() ), arr.end() );

    print(arr);
}
```

Ps. Using `int *arr, int arraySize` is not very C++ like. Please always try to use a proper container (which almost always will be `std::vector`).

EDIT:
I changed my answer a bit, because I found this speed comparison (and actuallty the whole question answered).
[What's the most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector)

Comment: OP states in comments: _my lecturer does not want us to use vectors_

Comment: OP cannot use standard library algorithms for that assignment. Also, in your solution the result array will be sorted, which might not be desired. Also, you do not need to use `for_each` to construct a set from vector.

Comment: @Ptaq666 good point. I replaced `for_each`. This enhanced the const correctness.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have not read this comment before posting my answer. Nevertheless, teaching C++ without proper container is ihmo not the right way to do it. There is no point in still using pointers and sizes if a `std::vector` can be used. C++ should be taught as shown in `A Tour of C++` by Stroustrup.

Comment: Where did the OP state that the algorithm functions couldn't be used?  I see that they cannot use `vector`, but `vector` is not an algorithm function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie he stated that in the comments to the question.

Comment: @schorsch312 -- Where in the comments is it stated that algorithm *functions* cannot be used?  Again `vector` is not an algorithm function.  STL consists of containers (which the OP says couldn't be used) and functions (which the OP has yet to say anything about).

Comment: @schorsch312 ok.  I commented in the main thread that the algorithm functions can be used on regular arrays, so there is no need to resort to vector.  But waiting for the OP to acknowledge whether that would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to imagine the algorithm having separate input and output arrays. Then, in pseudo-code:

```
for i = 0 to input_array_size-1
    Is input[i] equal to input[j] for any j between 0 and i-1?
    Yes - do nothing
    No - copy input[i] to output
```

To implement this with shared input and output, you need to have two array sizes, `input_array_size` and `output_array_size`. Then, the pseudo-code becomes

```
output_array_size = 0
for i = 0 to input_array_size-1
    Is array[i] equal to array[j] for any j between 0 and output_array_size-1?
    Yes - do nothing
    No:
        copy array[i] to array[output_array_size]
        Increase output_array_size
```

Note: it writes output where the input once was, so the check for duplicates should look at all elements that were output. For example, if your array is `1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 3`, then for the last `3` the accumulated output is `1, 2, 3, 5, 6`, and the code should compare all these with the current element.

---

To simplify debugging, where it says "do nothing", you can set current element to -1. This way, if you print your array during execution (for debugging), it will be clearer which elements were removed.

Answer (score 1):

there are only two changes made as you can see

1: you were traversing the whole array as you have declared a `posUsed=6` variable which is because there are only 6 elements so in in loops you need to traverse in array upto `posUsed` index like `i<posUsed` `j<posUsed` `k<posUsed`

2: the second changes is in j loop `j=i+1` because you don't need to compare the element of any index with element of the same index you have to compare it with elements after that index. if you compare it with same element it will be same and the program will delete that same element which results in ERROR.

onw more thing is that we don't traverse after `posUsed` index because after that the array is already empty/zero or null whatever you call it

and if you want to display just the non duplicated elements and not the zero's at the end of the array just add `if(arr[i]==0) return;` in the `printArray` function loop before `cout` statement

```
void deleteRepeats(int *arr, int arraySize, int& posUsed)
{
{
    for (int i = 0; i < posUsed; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < posUsed; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < posUsed; k++)
                {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                    
                }
            }
        
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using two pointers 
and if the array sorted

```
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        if(nums.size() == 0) return 0;
        int i = 0;

        for(int j = 1; j < nums.size(); j++)
            if(nums[j] != nums[i])  nums[++i] = nums[j];

        // return new array length
        return i + 1;
    }
```

```
//input: [1, 1, 2, 1] (arr1)
//output: 2 (returned length)
// print unique element
for(int i = 0; i < output; i++) cout << arr1[i] << '\n';
// [1, 2]
```

```
time complexity: O(N/2) -> O(N)
space complexity: O(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicate elements from an unsorted array by O(n^2) complexity.

```
    for (i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (vec[i] == vec[j])
            {
                vec[i] = -1; //Every duplicate element will replace by -1
            }
        }
    }

   for (i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vec[i] != -1)
        {
            copy.push_back(vec[i]);

     /*if you are using an array then store this value into a new array.
       first, declare a new array. The new array size will be equal to the 
       previous array. Like this :
       int newArr[sizeOfPreviousArrary];
       int j = 0;
       newArr[j] = arr[i]; 
       j++;
     */

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicate elements from an sorted array by O(n) complexity.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){
            vec.push_back(arr[i]);
        
        /*if you are using an array then store this value into a new array.
        first, declare a new array. The new array size will be equal to the 
        previous array. Note the array must be declared outside of the loop or it will be destroyed. 
        Like this :
            int newArr[sizeOfPreviousArrary];
            int j = 0;
            newArr[j] = arr[i]; 
            j++;
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map or set for deleting duplicates

```
void removeDuplicates(int arr[], int n)
{
  
    int i;
  
    // Initialise a set
    // to store the array values
    set<int> s;
  
    // Insert the array elements
    // into the set
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  
        // insert into set
        s.insert(arr[i]);
    }
  
    set<int>::iterator it;
  
    // Print the array with duplicates removed
    cout << "\nAfter removing duplicates:\n";
    for (it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << ", ";
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void removedup(int *arr, int &s)
{
    for (int i =0; i<s-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<s; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                for (int k=j; k<s-1; k++)
                {
                    arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                }
                s--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<s; i++)
    {
        cout << arr [i] <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl ;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "enter the size of array" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr [i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    removedup(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This C++ code is removing the duplicate elements of the entered array and giving the array with distinct elements only as output regardless whatever the size of the array and whatever the number of duplicate elements in the entered array.