# Ignoring duplicates in arrays

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble figuring out how to skip duplicate values in my array below.  The first array arrvalid holds the number while arrcpt holds the number of times the number appears.  Yet when i run the program it prints both values when i only want the value to be printed once.  Is there any way to correct this?

```
cout<<"Numbers chosen most: ";
int skip =0;

for(x=0;x<countval;x++)
{
    for(q=0;q<countval;q++)
    {
        if((arrvalid[x]==arrvalid[q])&&(arrcpt[x] == 2))
        {
            skip=q;     
        }
    }

    cout<<" "<<arrvalid[skip];

}
```

Output when q starts at 1: 93 93 34 34 34 34;

Comment: I think it's better if q starts at 1 in the second `for`, because arrvalid[0]==arrvalid[0].

Comment: Thanks for the comment i tried your suggest but it printed the numbers twice on each line. I had 93 in two different position in the array and would like it to not print all the times 93 appeared but rather just print that 93 appeared numerous times

Comment: My suggestion doesn't solve the problem. It merely eliminates the number of useless comparisons.

Comment: I understand that now however is there a way to solve this particular problem. I think there is but I am not sure how to reason it out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/)?
Set will make sure you cannot have duplicate records.

Edit: Example code.

[cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/63qcn)

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,1};
    std::set<int> unique(arr, arr+6);
    for (auto i : unique) {
        printf("%i", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
# Output: 12345
```

Comment: I have never heard about such a function but i will give it a try

Comment: I am not sure, but probably a `std::map` would be more suitable to solve that problem. Also `std::set` is a container class, not a _"function"_.

Comment: Start looking at std::vector. From there you can enhance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem. I prefer set over map when you have simple arrays or when you need to get unique objects from an non-unique source. But again, if it works, it works :)

Comment: @nauman Apparently the OP also wan'ts to count how often a specific value was _"skipped"_, thus a `std::map<int,int>` seems to be perfectly apropriate to solve the task.

Comment: i do courage you to provide your own answer if you truly believe its better. im not saying mine is better in any way but instead of pointing out faults, would it not be better if you gave your point of view in a good answer?