# C++ template function check unique vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stream, boolean

I am trying to write a templated function named `unique()` that detects if a `std::vector` only has unique elements, using only the `<vector>`, `<set>` and `<iostream>` headers.

```
template <typename T>
bool unique(const std::vector<T>& container){}
```

How can I manage to do this?

Comment: what did you try? What appears to be obvious to you is not obvious at all to others. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Think about how a `std::set` works, add some iterator magic and the solution might be a one-liner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually quite easy if you can use `std::set`.  Since `std::set` will only store unique items you can create a `std::set` from the `std::vector` and compare their sizes.  If they match then the vector has unique elements.  That would look like

```
template <typename T>
bool unique(const std::vector<T>& container)
{
    return container.size() == std::set<T>{container.begin(), container.end()}.size();
}
```

Comment: Oh I got it now. The set stream is quite useful

Comment: @cppp2020 Yes, the iterator pair constructor can be quite useful.  It should be noted that this is O(NlogN) complexity and uses O(N) space.  Not exactly efficient, but it does pretty well.  A `std::unordered_set` takes it down to O(N) complexity.

Comment: The question is almost a duplicate. At lease the answer certainly is: [What's the most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041620/10147399)

Comment: Note that set's require that the objects are less than comparable. So you need to provide this for T's that don't have it. Might be faster to copy the vector, sort it, and look for sequential matches. sets do a lot of heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::set<T> other{ container.begin(), container.end() );
return other.size() < container.size();
```

You can also break out early.

```
std::set<T> other;
for (auto&& e:container)
  if (!other.insert( e ).second)
    return false;
return true;
```