# How can i delete duplicate value in vector except last one

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a groups of coordinates(x,y,z) value in a vector in which first value and last value should be same but there is another coordinate in vector that is also common to first and last element in vector. i want to delete duplicate element in vector without changing the order.

below is my vector.

```
std::vector<std::vector<mi::math::Vector_struct<mi::Float32, 3> >> points;
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041620/10957435) close to what you need?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you are saying that:

- The first and last elements in the vector are equal.
- You want to remove all elements between those two that are equal to them.

If that is the case, you can use the standard remove+erase idiom but adjust the bounds:

```
// We need at least two elements to safely manipulate the iterators like this, and
// while we're testing the size we might as well make sure there's at least one
// element that could be removed.
if (points.size() >= 3) {
    // Removes all elements between the first and last element that are equal to
    // the first element.
    points.erase(
        std::remove(points.begin() + 1, points.end() - 1, points.front()),
        points.end() - 1
    );
}
```

Make sure you `#include <algorithm>` to get `std::remove()`.

---

Note that this code is comparing the outer vectors.  If you want to run this over each inner vector, just do that instead (loop over `points` and apply this code to each inner vector).  If you need to remove duplicates across multiple inner vectors, please clarify your question with more details.