# Remove only first met element in stl list

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, stl, iterator

I've got a list of elements stored in stl c++ list. How to remove only one of repeating values?

```
#include <list>
int main() {
    std::list<int> listOfInts({ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 });
    listOfInts.remove(3);
    return 0;
}
```

My list will now look like this: 1, 2, 4, 5.
Is there a way to make it look like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

I know it might be very easy, but it's my first time with stl list and I appreciate all tips.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector)

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: @Quarra: Removing duplicates will reduce the number of copies **to** one, not **by** one. E.g. if the input was `1,2,3,3,3,4,5`, removing only the first occurrence of  `3` would leave `1,2,3,3,4,5` - still a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Use the standard algorithm `std::find`

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...
auto it = std::find( std::begin( listOfInts ), std::end( listOfInts ), 3 );

if ( it != std::end( listOfInts ) ) listOfInts.erase( it );
```

Comment: Don't actually need all those `std::`  there. After `std::list<int> listOfInts` ADL will find the `std` namespace.

Comment: Works perfectly, now it's time to analyze this piece of code, thank you!

Comment: @MSalters Using qualified names makes the code more readable.

Comment: that's quite the subjective statement, personally I think it's way more readable without namespace clutter

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `std::begin(listOfInts)` over `listOfInts.begin()`?

Comment: @NathanPierson Using a more general approach is better. In this case you can for example substitute the list for an array.

Comment: well as I said, you can't really speak from my perspective

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<int> listOfInts({ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 });

    auto itr = find(listOfInts.begin(), listOfInts.end(), 3);

    if (itr != listOfInts.end()) {
        listOfInts.erase(itr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```