# The code is erasing just one dublicates and not another. Why so?

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9kMu.png)

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> intersection(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        
         vector<int>v;
         sort(nums1.begin(),nums1.end());
         sort(nums2.begin(),nums2.end());
        for(int i=1;i<nums1.size();i++)
        {
           if(nums1[i]==nums1[i-1])
               nums1.erase(nums1.begin()+i);            
        }
         for(int i=1;i<nums2.size();i++)
        {
              if(nums2[i]==nums2[i-1])
               nums2.erase(nums2.begin()+i);    
        }
        for(int i=0;i<nums1.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<nums2.size();j++)
            {
                if(nums1[i]==nums2[j])
                {
                    v.push_back(nums1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
        
    }
};
```

While I am comparing in both the vectors i am trying to erase dublicate elements. But eventually end up in erasing just one dublicate element and not another.The first three lines denotes vector after sorting and last denotes removing of dublicates

Comment: For more than exercise code, also check std::set_intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the first 2 loops, you are erasing an element in a `std::vector`, from within a loop traversing its elements. This is a bad idea because the `std::vector`'s size and element indices will change. A similar issue arrised when you use iterators which are invalidated by using `erase`. See: [std::vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)
2. You can see here info how to do it correctly: [What's the most efficient way to erase duplicates and sort a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector)
3. `intersection` does not access any class members (because there aren't any). It could be made into a free function, or a `static` method of class `Solution` (if it makes sense to put it in there).
4. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
5. Please avoid posting images of used data. Instead copy-paste it as text so that it's easy for us to test.

Comment: my doubt got resolved and will make sure about attaching media :)

Comment: @tanmaysaxena Please correct the image description or better copy the text if the existing question. Others should be able to look it up comfortably.

Comment: @Sebastian sure :)