C++ function returns extremely slowly, far slower than functionally equivalent Python code
I have a function that is used in a script that I am writing to remove redundant blocking keywords from a list. Basically, with the input (in any order) of:
{"apple", "bapple", "banana", "cherry", "bananaman", "sweetherrypie", "sweet", "b"}

It should output a shrunk array of strings (in any order) of:
{"apple", "cherry", "sweet", "b"}

This is done to reduce the number of keywords a matching algorithm needs to pass through as a personal learning project (If a string contained "banana", it would also contain "b" so "banana" is unnecessary, and can be discarded
It needed to be extremely performant, as it had to run on lists of over 10,000,000 strings.
Initially, I wrote some Python code to do this:
def deduplicate_keywords(keywords):
    def inner_loop(unique_keywords, keyword):
        for unique_keyword in unique_keywords:
            # Check if the current keyword includes any of the unique keywords
            if unique_keyword in keyword:
                return  # Match so it is not added to unique keywords
        # If the keyword does not include any of the shorter keywords, add it to unique_keywords
        unique_keywords.append(keyword)
        return

    # Remove duplicates and sort the keywords by length in ascending order
    keywords = sorted(set(keywords), key=len)
    unique_keywords = []

    for keyword in keywords:
        inner_loop(unique_keywords, keyword)
    return unique_keywords

And a performance benchmark to measure its performance:
class TestDeduplicateKeywords(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_performance_intensive_case(self):
        keywords = [
            "abcdef",
            "def",
            "ghidef",
            "jkl",
            "mnop",
            "qrst",
            "uvwxyz",
            "ghijkl",
            "abcdefgh",
            "ijklmnop",
            "mnopqrstuv",
            "rstuvwx",
            "mnopqrstuvwx",
            "uvwx",
        ]

        # Extending the list to make it very long and complex
        base_keywords = keywords[:]
        for i in range(200000):
            base_keywords.extend([f"{k}{i}" for k in keywords])
            base_keywords.extend([f"{i}{k}" for k in keywords])
            base_keywords.extend([f"{i}{k}{i}" for k in keywords])

        keywords = base_keywords

        old_function_time = 0
        new_function_time = 0

        for repeat in range(100): 
            # This loop (not present in the C++ code) is used to loop it multiple times to find an average
            start_time = time.time()
            result = deduplicate_keywords(keywords)
            end_time = time.time()
            old_function_time = (
                repeat * old_function_time + (end_time - start_time)
            ) / (repeat + 1)
            start_time = time.time()
            result = deduplicate_keywords_new(keywords) 
            # Above is a function that can be edited to check whether changes speed up the code
            end_time = time.time()
            new_function_time = (
                repeat * new_function_time + (end_time - start_time)
            ) / (repeat + 1)

        # As the list is extended with numbers, the result will be unique non-redundant keywords
        expected_result = ["def", "jkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx"]

        self.assertEqual(set(result), set(expected_result))
        print(
            f"Test performance_intensive_case for old function took {old_function_time} seconds\n"
            f"Test performance_intensive_case for new function took {new_function_time} seconds\n"
        )

        if old_function_time < new_function_time:
            print(f"Old is faster than new")
        else:
            print(f"New is faster than old")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

This was too slow for my needs at 5.677098312377932 seconds on my weak laptop (when ran 100 times to find an average time) given by the console log:
.Test performance_intensive_case for old function took 5.677098312377932 seconds

Therefore, I tried writing the same thing in C++ to see whether I would net a performance gain. It was so much slower, so I added some timing code to the function itself to see where the slowdown was. Here is the function:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>

std::vector<std::string> deduplicate_keywords(const std::vector<std::string> &keywords)
{
    auto t_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto inner_loop = [](std::vector<std::string> &unique_keywords, const std::string &keyword)
    {
        for (const auto &unique_keyword : unique_keywords)
        {
            if (keyword.find(unique_keyword) != std::string::npos)
            {
                return; // Match so it is not added to unique keywords
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, add it to unique_keywords
        unique_keywords.push_back(keyword);
    };

    // Remove duplicates using a set
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "started old function!" << std::endl;
    std::set<std::string> unique_set(keywords.begin(), keywords.end());
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "removed duplicates in " << std::chrono::duration<double>(t2 - t1).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    // Convert set back to vector and sort by length
    auto t3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::string> sorted_keywords(unique_set.begin(), unique_set.end());
    std::sort(sorted_keywords.begin(), sorted_keywords.end(), [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
              { return a.length() < b.length(); });
    auto t4 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Sorted by length in " << std::chrono::duration<double>(t4 - t3).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    // Filter out redundant keywords
    auto t5 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<std::string> unique_keywords;
    for (const auto &keyword : sorted_keywords)
    {
        inner_loop(unique_keywords, keyword);
    }
    auto t6 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Filtered in " << std::chrono::duration<double>(t6 - t5).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    auto t_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto total_time = std::chrono::duration<double>(t_end - t_start).count();
    std::cout << "Total function time: " << total_time << " seconds" << std::endl;

    return unique_keywords;
}

Along with the performance benchmark:
using Time = std::chrono::steady_clock;
void test_performance_intensive_case()
{
    std::cout << "Keywords generation start." << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> keywords = {
        "abcdef", "def", "ghidef", "jkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwxyz",
        "ghijkl", "abcdefgh", "ijklmnop", "mnopqrstuv", "rstuvwx",
        "mnopqrstuvwx", "uvwx"};

    // Extending the list to make it very long and complex
    std::vector<std::string> base_keywords = keywords;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; ++i)
    {
        for (const auto &k : keywords)
        {
            base_keywords.push_back(k + std::to_string(i));
            base_keywords.push_back(std::to_string(i) + k);
            base_keywords.push_back(std::to_string(i) + k + std::to_string(i));
        }
    }

    auto keywords_extended = base_keywords;
    std::cout << "Keywords generated!" << std::endl;
    std::set<std::string> expected_result = {"def", "jkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx"};

    // One time variable declaration for "for loop"
    // The total times are use to confirm that timing itself had no negative impact on the times
    double old_function_time = 0;
    double new_function_time = 0;
    double total_test_time = 0;
    double total_test_time_new = 0;
    double average_old_time = 0;
    double average_new_time = 0;
    Time::time_point start_time_total;
    Time::time_point start_time;
    Time::time_point end_time;
    Time::time_point end_time_total;
    Time::time_point start_time_total_new;
    Time::time_point start_time_new;
    Time::time_point end_time_new;
    Time::time_point end_time_total_new;
    std::cout << "vars declared and loop of code about to start" << std::endl;
    for (int repeat_no = 0; repeat_no < 5; ++repeat_no) // Loop to calculate average.
    {
        start_time_total = Time::now();
        start_time = Time::now();
        std::vector<std::string> result_old = deduplicate_keywords(keywords_extended);
        end_time = Time::now();
        old_function_time = std::chrono::duration<double>(end_time - start_time).count();
        end_time_total = Time::now();
        total_test_time = std::chrono::duration<double>(end_time_total - start_time_total).count();
        assert(std::set<std::string>(result_old.begin(), result_old.end()) == expected_result);
        average_old_time = (repeat_no * average_old_time + old_function_time) / (repeat_no + 1);
        std::cout << "Current average old time: " << average_old_time << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Old function time: " << old_function_time << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total test case time: " << total_test_time << " seconds" << std::endl;

        start_time_total_new = Time::now();
        start_time_new = Time::now();
        std::vector<std::string> result_new = deduplicate_keywords_new(keywords_extended); // same as in the python code, useful for comparison
        end_time_new = Time::now();
        new_function_time = std::chrono::duration<double>(end_time_new - start_time_new).count();
        end_time_total_new = Time::now();
        total_test_time_new = std::chrono::duration<double>(end_time_total_new - start_time_total_new).count();
        assert(std::set<std::string>(result_new.begin(), result_new.end()) == expected_result);
        average_new_time = (repeat_no * average_new_time + new_function_time) / (repeat_no + 1);
        std::cout << "Current average new time: " << average_new_time << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "New function time: " << new_function_time << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total test case time: " << total_test_time_new << " seconds" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "End of intense function runs." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average old function time: " << average_old_time << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average new function time: " << average_new_time << " seconds" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Test performance intensive case for old function took " << average_old_time
              << " seconds but new function took " << average_new_time << " seconds" << std::endl;

    if (average_old_time < average_new_time)
    {
        std::cout << "Old is faster than new" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (average_old_time == average_new_time)
    {
        std::cout << "They take the same time" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "New is faster than old" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    test_performance_intensive_case();
    return 0;
}

This outputted to the terminal (shortened, removing the logs for the currently empty deduplicate_keywords_new function) this:
started old function!
removed duplicates in 9.64173 seconds
Sorted by length in 3.36138 seconds
Filtered in 0.366933 seconds
Total function time: 21.0037 seconds
old function time: 405.213 seconds
Total test case time: 405.213 seconds

Aside from the general speed reduction, the logs seem to indicate that returning the function (return unique keywords) seems to take extremely long. This can be deduced by the fact that std::cout << "old function time: " << old_function_time << " seconds" << std::endl; exists outside the function and so the only thing that could cause the slowdown is the return statement in the original code. Why is this? And what can I do to stop this? I am fairly new to C++ coding and development, so it would be great if your explanations were detailed and thorough.
Compilation and other factors
The compilation flags that I was using were -g -O3 -std=c++17. It would seem that this would not be the cause of part of the issue, however, it seems that it did. Because I don't use C++ that often, I stuck to using VSCode and used the C/C++ extension with a build task that contained those arguments. I did this for ease of use - now I could just click 1 button and the code would compile and run. Turns out that because I clicked that button, the code was run in a semi-debug mode, with no debug functionality, but the code was run equally slowly. This led to the horrendous times. This problem was mostly mitigated through the use of running the code manually through the terminal.
So lesson learned... when coding in C++ in VSCode, don't speed test code by clicking the run button, just build first and then run the executable, through the terminal.
This did provide a significant speedup. Now the code performs almost as fast, but still slower than the Python code, as can be seen in this new console log:
started old function!
removed duplicates in 3.2457 seconds
Sorted by length in 1.83285 seconds
Filtered in 0.327369 seconds
Total function time: 5.60095 seconds
old function time: 6.46725 seconds
Total test case time: 6.46725 seconds

Effects of running repeats
Now that my code's run time had reduced to a reasonable size, I decided to run 100 repeats of the C++ code to get an accurate picture of my code's run time. Turns out my initial code was somewhat of an outlier in terms of runtime and the most representative times that I could get was:
Average old function time: 5.96633 seconds

As you can see, the 5.96633 seconds it took is longer than the 5.7 seconds that the Python code took. Why does this gap still exist? And how could I rewrite the code to make it faster? The code in both seems logically identical at first glance.

Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

FWIW, if you want to take a collection of strings and get a collection of unique strings its as easy as std::set unique_words{word_list.begin(), word_list.end()};  You can also use a std::unordered_set, not sure which one would be faster.

@NathanOliver It's not a unique collection of strings. If one string is a substring of another, they only want the substring.

I tried writing the same thing in cpp Remember, CPP is C PreProcessor or a file extension.  Don't deface C++ name.

in release mode with optimizations turned on, it takes about half a second.

@OP Any question concerning the performance of C++ code must be accompanied by the compiler options used to build the application.  The most important of these options are the compiler optimization settings used.  If you are timing an unoptimized or "debug" build, then the timings you are showing are meaningless.  Here is your code with optimization -O3 used.

As a rule of thumb, if your C++ code is slower than an equivalent Python code, there is something wrong with your algorithm, implementation or optimization settings.  Python should be slower since it's an interpretive language (unless you've compiled your Python code for the native implementation).

BTW, you do some copy (instead of move)...

This version can do 50,000 in 3 seconds (godbolt times out for larger counts). It optimizes sorting and removing duplicates part, where you copy lots of strings around several times.

no comment that was a typo, fixed now, thanks for pointing that out. No clue how I even made a mistake in copying code! @user4581301 I added your suggestions.

To speed it up, you may want to move the the code from the lambda to instide the loop.

@IgorTandetnik: and avoiding copies of std::make_tuple with std::forward_as_tuple is even better Demo

@pts I tried that before (you can see in edit 1) where I took out the previous code which used the goto and replaced it with this. I compared both in terms of speed and there was no speed difference anyways. They seemed to take the exact same time which suggests that they compiled to the same assembly. I really just did that to avoid the inevitable complaints about using a goto and the bad code that it often ends in.

You could use unordered_set instead of set, since the order doesn't matter at that point (you are copying it to a vector which will be ordered). If you want to, you could also try another sorting algorithm. Also, consider using "const" where you can (ex: for the variable "unique_set" ) since that could help the compiler to optimize your code.

Creating a set manually could also be faster than using the constructor, as refered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector

I think you should move or copy this question to codereview.stackexchange.com. Point is, that there is so much that could be improved on the C++ side and that would also affect performance, that it's hard to tell if you really have a problem. Just to illustrate that, the answer is probably to not do things that aren't necessary. BTW: As a rough estimate, how long does it take to just read the keywords and sort them? Removing irrelevant ones should not take much longer.

@Jarod42 Thanks for your help. Your code is fast enough for my requirements, taking 1.88082 seconds to run on average over 100 times on the performance benchmark. Although faster is better, I think this is a point to say good enough is good enough and just accept the time. If you write up your code into an answer and explain thoroughly why it is so much faster, I would be happy to mark it as correct. It would be helpful to learn why what you did caused such a performance increase.

@Victor I tried changing the set to be unordered and it resulted in a ~3 second slowdown to 8.53 seconds.

@UlrichEckhardt This is a console log from a fairly normal run of Jarod42's code: removed duplicates in 1.54257 seconds, Filtered in 0.310756 seconds, Destructed in 1.4e-06 seconds, Total function time: 1.85414 seconds, Current average new time: 1.85434 seconds New function time: 1.85434 seconds Total test case time: 1.85434 seconds.  For my original code, the console log in edit 2 suggests a max of around 5 seconds (removed duplicates time + sorted by length time), and if this was the complete max, a minimum time of above 4.5 seconds.

The "sort and remove duplicates" part is unnecessarily complicated. It could be done in a few lines:
// Sort by length, and then alphabetically for strings of same length
std::sort(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(),
    [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(a.length(), a) <
               std::forward_as_tuple(b.length(), b);
    });
// Remove duplicates
keywords.erase(std::unique(keywords.begin(), keywords.end()), keywords.end());

Demo. Takes ~1.3 sec with the generation loop of 50,000 and an average over 5 runs (I had to reduce the parameters enough so the online compiler wouldn't time out).

Thanks! I would also like to add that on OP's system it takes 1.88082 seconds on average to run a 200,000-time generation loop over 100 times, to keep its benchmarking criteria consistent with the other Python code

This is only a partial answer focusing on Python only, but it's too long to be written as a comment.
In general, the Python interpreter is slow, and the same algorithm implemented in Python can be as much as 10 or 100 times slower than in C++. This is clearly not the case for your code. That's because your Python program spends most of its time in the Python standard library (such as the C implementation of the substring-check in operator), which is outside the Python interpreter. It happens that for your code, the Python standard library is faster than the C++ standard library.
This is surprising, but not completely impossible. It's surprising, because implementations of the C++ standard library are typically highly optimized.

It's possible to make your code faster by making it use fewer functions and less Python code, like this:
def deduplicate_keywords2(keywords):
    unique_keywords = []
    for keyword in sorted(set(keywords), key=len):
        for unique_keyword in unique_keywords:
            if unique_keyword in keyword:
                break
        else:
            unique_keywords.append(keyword)
    return unique_keywords

And this:
def deduplicate_keywords3(keywords):
    unique_keywords = []
    for keyword in sorted(set(keywords), key=len):
        if not any(unique_keyword in keyword for unique_keyword in unique_keywords):
            unique_keywords.append(keyword)
    return unique_keywords

On my computer, version 2 was about 15% faster than your original, and version 3 was 20% slower (!) than your original. Apparently any(...) with a generator expression is slower than the direct loop.
When defining a function with def, Python generates bytecode. When calling the function, the Python interpreter executes the instructions within the bytecode. Use dis to dump the bytecode:
import dis
dis.dis(deduplicate_keywords)
print('---')
dis.dis(deduplicate_keywords2)
print('---')
dis.dis(deduplicate_keywords3)

A rule of thumb: the shorter the bytecode, the faster the interpreter executes it.

I ran both of your functions. For the second one, I only ran 5 times and in those it was clear that it was slower, seeing a near 50% speed decrease on average over those ten runs at 7.39 seconds. The first one was quicker on average over 100 runs, but not by an especially large margin, as on your machine, at 4.3% quicker, seen through Test performance_intensive_case for new function took 5.44 seconds. Still though, Iearnt something new. Didn't know you could use if else functions in Python like that. Spent a good 5 seconds finding where the if was for the else, until I looked up and right.

@user26571886 It's not if-else, it's for-else. The else has nothing to do with the if.

I had no clue that actually exists! Very helpful to know and aids in understanding the actual working of the code code.
